# Unnecessary Image box in RDLC report

Tags: dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have developed one report using .net rdlc. In that report it is showing image box. although I did not used image in the report. I have also checked the xml of the rdlc report . The xml also dose not have any image.

Please help me.

Thanks!

[The site dose not allow me to upload image :) ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following line of code in head section under **style** tag which will remove blank image from the RDLC.

```
<style>
    body:nth-of-type(1) img[src*="Blank.gif"] {
        display: none;
    }
</style
```

[image]

above is the sample problem in RDLC report in report viewer.